# TryParse equivalent of Convert with invariantculture

Tags: c#, culture, tryparse

In my code I frequently use the following Converts:

```
Convert.ToInt32(value, Cultureinfo.InvariantCulture);
Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I now do like to use TryParse functions because of recent errors. I'm not entirely sure if i'm correct in using the following equivalents as I do not completely understand the NumberStyles enum.

```
Int64.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.invariantCulture, out output);
Decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out output);
```

EDIT BELOW after answers

The following code should then be the correct alternative:

```
Int64.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out output);
Decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out output);
```

Comment: Your approach is correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read about `NumberStyles` in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Essentially it allows you to specify what sort of text will parse.

If you want to be as flexible as possible, then `NumberStyles.Any` is the 'widest' option.

`Convert.ToInt32` is equivalent to using `int.Parse` and `Convert.ToDecimal` is equivalent to using `decimal.Parse` - they delegate to these methods.

Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) for `int.Parse`, the default is `NumberStyles.Integer`.  And per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z(v=vs.110).aspx) for `decimal.Parse`, the default is `NumberStyles.Number`.  If you want to be consistent with the behaviour of `Convert.ToInt32` and `Convert.ToDecimal`, you should use these values.

Comment: Wouldn't `NumberStyles.Any | NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier` be the wider option than just `NumberStyles.Any`, or would that combination be illegal?

Comment: I changed the question with your and dcastro's answer tyvm

Comment: @stakx it seems it's illegal.  The docs say *The only flags that can be combined with AllowHexSpecifier are AllowLeadingWhite and AllowTrailingWhite.*.  I tried it and got an exception to that effect.

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation for Int64.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h(v=vs.110).aspx) says `NumberStyles.Integer` is the default:

> The s parameter is interpreted using the NumberStyles.Integer style. In addition to the decimal digits, only leading and trailing spaces together with a leading sign are allowed.

For [Decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx), it's `NumberStyles.Number`:

> Parameter s is interpreted using the NumberStyles.Number style. This means that white space and thousands separators are allowed but currency symbols are not.

Comment: This would explicitly not correspond with `decimal` which can have floating values. `NumberStyles.Float` would be more appropriate, given the two usecases in the question (or  just generally `NumberStyles.Number)`.

Comment: I changed the question with your and charles mager's answer tyvm

Answer (score 4):

Yes your approach is correct, both approaches should give the same results.

The implementation of `Convert.ToInt32(string s)` is as follows:

```
public static int ToInt32(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    if (value == null)
        return 0;
    return Int32.Parse(value, NumberStyles.Integer, provider);
 }
```

So as you can see internally one method calls the other - the only difference is that with `Convert` you don't have control over the number style - it is hardcoded to `NumberStyles.Integer`. If you want identical functionality you should specify this enum value in your calls to `TryParse`.

Source code for the `Convert` class is available [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs).

May I also point out that you are calling `Int64.TryParse` when if `Convert.ToInt32` was sufficient then so should be `Int32.TryParse`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I have two suggestions: **1.** Cite your sources! (How did you come by the implementation of `Convert.ToInt32`?) **2.** Your answer suggests that `NumberStyles.Integer` would be the one to go for; but you initially say that the OP's current code is equivalent (they use `NumberStyles.Any`). Perhaps you could go more into `NumberStyles.Any`.

Comment: I reflected into `mscorlib` - no need to cite that :)

Comment: Actually, you *should* say so. Reverse-engineering an assembly, apart from possible legal issues (but IANAL), results in knowledge that might be subject to change at any time. I'd say one should prefer the Reference Source (the name says it all) over decompilation when answering on SO. That's just my opinion, though.

Comment: I added a link to MS Reference Source.

Comment: I changed the question with dcastro's and charles mager's answer, your answer to was very helpful for me to understand more of the Convert.ToInt methods +1